# Import multiple files from a folder in Python

Tags: python, import

I have a folder in my Application directory called Commands.folder. What I want to do is import all the modules in that folder, regardless of the name, into the python file that imports. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from Commands import *
```

You should create an empty file named "`__init__.py`" in the "Commands" folder, and your main app script should be in the "Application" folder you've mentioned.

Note however, the "from module import *" is not recommended since it may cause namespace pollution.

Read [this](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that very important file requirement. Is there anything I can do to customize the init file?

Comment: Yes. You can specify which modules to include by adding a list named '__all__' in it. See Python documentation: 

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Answer (score 2):

If you start your program in Application, you can import all modules in /Commands using:

```
from Commands import *
```